# Zeppelin - twice the same show(), two different results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I am new to Zeppelin, perhaps my question is naive. At first, I get the basic data like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sql
val dfOriginal = sql("SELECT CAST(event_type_id AS STRING), event_time  FROM sl_event SORT BY event_time LIMIT 200")

+-------------+--------------------+ 
|event_type_id| event_time| 
+-------------+--------------------+ 
| 23882|2018-05-03 11:41:...| 
| 23882|2018-05-03 11:41:...| 
| 23882|2018-05-03 11:41:...| 
| 25681|2018-05-03 11:41:...| 
| 23882|2018-05-03 11:41:...| 
| 2370|2018-05-03 11:41:...| 
| 23882|2018-05-03 11:41:...|
...
```

I have 200 records like this.

I calculate occurrences of even types like this:

```
val dfIndividual = dfOriginal.groupBy("event_type_id").count().sort(-col("count"))
dfIndividual.show(200)
```

I am confused: whenever I execute this (in Zeppelin), I have **different** results. For example:

```
+-------------+-----+
|event_type_id|count| 
+-------------+-----+ 
| 24222| 30| 
| 10644| 16| 
| 21164| 9|
...
```

or - just few seconds later:

```
+-------------+-----+ 
|event_type_id|count| 
+-------------+-----+ 
| 5715| 34| 
| 3637| 19| 
| 3665| 17| 
| 9280| 13|
...
```

The difference between these two results scares me seriously. Where is the problem? Is it Zeppelin? Underlying Spark? How to assure that I will get reproducible results here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only reasons I can think of is that

a) the source table `sl_event` has changed in the meantime. As you did not cache in results, any action you call (e.g. `show`) will re-evaluate everything

or b) you have many events with the same `event_time`, so order by `event_time limit 200` will not give you consistent results, try `SORT BY event_time, event_type_id  LIMIT 200` in your first query, or even better use an unique id your second ordering column

Comment: b) was the case